# Azure subscription is not visible in default directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have created a free trail subscription in my azure account and the administrator for that trail subscription is set to my default directory account (only directory I have). But under the default directory, no subscriptions are listed. So I cannot create any services under it.

Comment: Its resolved, it took some time to reflect the new details.

Comment: You can add an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Its resolved, it took some time to reflect under the default directory.